# Boundary Conditions on the Magnetic Flux Density (B-field)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, physics, vector-fields, electromagnetism

My question is similar to this one ([Boundary conditions magnetic field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3642307/boundary-conditions-magnetic-field)) in that it is related to the boundary conditions of the magnetic field (B-field). However, my question focuses on mathematically characterizing physicists' claims regarding the boundary conditions of the B-field (eq2 below). Simply put, **my question is the mathematical proof of Conjection, below**.

Assume that the space $\mathbb{R}^3$ is subdivided into two connected components $M_1$ and $M_2$ by a smooth 2-dimensional manifold $S$ (the figure enlarges only a part of $S$).
That means,  $\mathbb{R}^3 =M_1 \cup S \cup M_2$ and $M_1$,$S$,$M_2$ are disjoint.

[image]

In　the physics, when considering the B-fields in materials,
the  B-field, $\textbf{B}: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is $C^{\infty}$ at both inside of $M_1$ and inside of $M_2$, but they did not mention of the behavior of the $\textbf{B}$ on the $S$, that is the boundary between $M_1$ and $M_2$.

However, according to Maxwell's equations, the B-fields are characterized as a vector field that satisfies $div[B]=0$. This means that if we take a micro cylinder $V$ that 'sandwiches' the curved surface $S$ in the sense of definition 1 below,
$$\int \int_{S_1}\textbf{B} +\int \int_{S2}\textbf{B} +\int \int_{S_3}\textbf{B} =\int \int \int_{V} div[B] =0 \ \ (eq,1)$$

Here,

- the radius of this micro cylinder $V$ is $r$ and the height is $h$.
- ${S}_{1}$ represents the upper base of this micro cylinder
- ${S}_{3}$ represents the side surface of this micro cylinder
- ${S}_{2}$ represnts the bottom surface of this micro cylinder

Perhaps if we take a mathematically accurate position, more precisely, $div[B]=0$ should be rephrased as follows:

- For all $\mathbf{x} \in Int[M_1]\cup Int[M_2]$ , $div[B](x)=0$

**Def 1 (Sandwiching $S$ at $\textbf{x}_0\in S$)**

> Suppose that
>
> - a smooth surface $S$ separates $\mathbb{R}^3$ into two connected components, $M_1$ and $M_2$,
> - $\textbf{x}_0\in S$ ,and
> - $\mathbf{n}(x_0)$ is the unit normal of $S$ at $\textbf{x}_0\in S $, 
>   Then, **the micro cylinder$V$ sandwiching $S$ at $\textbf{x}_0$** ,  iff all of the following conditions are satisfied;
> - $\textbf{x}_0\in Int[V]$, Int means open kernel
> - $S_1\subset M_1 $ and  $S_2\subset M_2$
> - $S_1 \perp\mathbf{n}(x_0)\ $ and $S_2\perp\mathbf{n}(x_0)$
> - Both of the distance between $S_1$ and $\textbf{x}_0$ and the distance between $S_2$ and $\textbf{x}_0$  are $h/2$.

In other words, in the figure below, in (1) $V$ sandwiches $S$, but in (2) it does not sandwich $S$ in the sense of Definition 1;
[image]

So far, the story may be clear to me, but...

Physicists argue that by 'making' $S_2$ sufficiently small compared to $S_1$ and $S_3$, the following holds;
$$\lim_{r\to 0, h\to 0} \textbf{B}(\textbf{x}_0+ \frac{h}{2}\mathbf{n}(\textbf{x}_0)) \cdot \mathbf{n}(\textbf{x}_0)
=\lim_{r\to 0, h\to 0} \textbf{B}(\textbf{x}_0 - \frac{h}{2}\mathbf{n}(x_0)) \cdot \mathbf{n}(\textbf{x}_0)
\ \ (eq2)$$

**However, mathematically, there seems to be at least the following gap between (eq1) and (eq2);**

- Is it possible to make $S_1$ and $S_2$ become infinitely small while keeping $S_3$ sufficiently small relative to $S_1$ and $S_2$?
- When the side surface,$S_3$ is made sufficiently small compared to the top and botttom surfaces, $S_1$ and $S_3$, can $V$ sandwichs $S$ in the sense of Def1?

I think this question will probably be resolved if the following predictions are correct.

**Conjection:**

> Suppose that a smooth surface $S$ separates $\mathbb{R}^3$
> into two connected components $M_1$ and $M_2$. 
> Let $\textbf{x}_0\in S$, and
> $\mathbf{n}(x_0)$ is the unit normal of $S$ at $\textbf{x}_0\in S $,
>
> At this time, there are
>
> - ${r_i}  , h_i \ (i=1,2,\cdots) $, sequence of $\mathbb{R}$ and,
> - $V_{i} \ (i=1,2,\cdots) $,  a series of micro cylinders with radius $r_i$ and height $h_i$
>
> such that,
>
> - (0)$r_i>0$ and  $h_i >0$, for all $i=1,2,\cdots $
> - (1) $V_{i}$ sandwiches $S$ at $\textbf{x}_0$ in the sense of Def 1, for all $i=1,2,\cdots$
> - (2)$\lim_{i\to \infty} h_{i} = \lim_{i\to \infty} r_{i} = 0$
> - (3)$\lim_{i\to \infty} h_{i} /r_{i} = 0$

Of course, it would be relatively easy to create $h_i$ and $r_i$ that satisfy the conditions (2) and (3) above; for example, if the following is defined, these satisfy (2) and (3) above.

- $r_i := 1/i$
- $h_i := {r_i}^2$

However, whether the above point sequence satisfies (1) probably depends on $S$.

**My questions:**

> - Is the above Conjection correct, or can it be corrected by adding some conditions?
> - If so, please provide proof (with additional conditions), and
> - if it is difficult to correct, please provide a counterexample.

**See also**

- https://www.circuitbread.com/textbooks/electromagnetics-i/magnetostatics/boundary-conditions-on-the-magnetic-flux-density-b